# Is it possible to calculate CPU utilization from load average & top CPU% column

Tags: top, cpu-usage, uptime, load-average

I have a file which contains 2 output of uptime load average & CPU% column like an output from top command.

So, is it possible to calculate it into CPU utilization or CPU usage at a time?

Example:

```
=====================================================================
        APPLIANCE CPU USAGE
=====================================================================

0.90 1.05 0.84 1/151 13615

=====================================================================
        APPLIANCE PROCESSES
=====================================================================

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2184   700 ?        Ss   22:48   0:00 init [3]                          
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [migration/0]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   22:48   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [migration/1]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   22:48   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [events/0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [events/1]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [khelper]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [kthread]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [kblockd/0]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [kblockd/1]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [kacpid]
root       163  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [cqueue/0]
root       164  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [cqueue/1]
root       167  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [khubd]
root       169  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [kseriod]
root       242  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:48   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root       243  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:48   0:00 [pdflush]
root       244  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    22:48   0:00 [pdflush]
root       245  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [kswapd0]
root       246  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [aio/0]
root       247  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:48   0:00 [aio/1]
root       411  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       440  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [ata/0]
root       441  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [ata/1]
root       442  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [ata_aux]
root       446  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       447  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       448  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       449  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       450  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root       451  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root       452  1.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [kjournald]
root       469  2.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [kauditd]
root       497  3.0  0.0   2368   672 ?        S<s  22:49   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1395  4.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [kjournald]
root      1397  5.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [kjournald]
root      1399  6.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   22:49   0:00 [kjournald]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate cpu% with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
FILE=<file path>  
CPU_USAGE=`sed -n 'H; /^USER/h; ${g;p;}' $FILE | awk '{print $3}' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum ;}'` 
CPU_CORES=`nproc --all`
ACTUAL_CPU_USAGE=`echo "$CPU_USAGE $CPU_CORES" | awk '{print $1/$2"%"}'`
echo "CPU : $ACTUAL_CPU_USAGE"
```

Comment: You would probably want to know the number of CPUs as well, as you would otherwise possibly get a number greater than 100. You could also combine your `sed` and twe `awk` invocations into a single `awk` program.

Comment: @Kusalananda good catch.i have updated my answer.

Comment: @SivaPrasath Unfortunately, the appliance is Linux hardened. It doesn't support bash shell & common Linux command. It only has CPU info as my post. That's why I want to calculate CPU usage from that.

Comment: if possible copy the file to another system and calculate.otherwise we have to satisfy with the first variable in CPU load. which is average CPU% usage of past 1 minute

Comment: @SivaPrasath Is total of %CPU column in 1 minute the same thing with the first variable in load average?

Comment: Yes.It's the cumulative average of %cpu used for past 1 min.

Comment: No, load average is not tied to % CPU usage. Load average is the number of processes waiting on run time. Things other than a busy CPU can drive this number up, such as IO wait.

Comment: @Patrick That definition suits for single core processor. Now we are in the era of multi core...To make it clear , 0.8 load means 80% of CPU used in 1 core. If  2.4 load  in a quad core processor means,  100 % used in 2 cores and 40% used in 3rd core. So total CPU usage is 60%= (240/4).

Comment: No it does not. You can have a load of 500 with a completely idle CPU. As I stated, load is the number of processes waiting on run time. Not the usage of the CPU.

Comment: http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages